# Is there a way to collapse the list of processors in htop?

Tags: top, cpu-usage, htop

Now that I have a computer with 64 processors, I have a real display problem with `htop`.

When I look at the screen in my console, all I see are the 64 processors and nothing about what's running (well, one line).

Under X-Windows I can make the console bigger with <kbd>F11</kbd>, but that means I can't see my other windows.

When I use `top`, I can hit the <kbd>1</kbd> key and either all the CPUs are shown or collapsed into just one entry.

Do we have a way to do that in `htop`?

I have to say that having *too many CPUs* renders `htop` rather useless in that sense.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/806619/102934

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running htop, hit F2 or 'S' to enter the setup screen, from there you should be able to change the screen  display settings,. the first column 'setup'  is a global settings menu, maybe the more useful setting for tree listing of processes might be of interest to you in there. The screen display is split in half vertically so that you can view the same information in different formats side by side, however for folk like myself who have anything from 256 to 4096 CPU's on their compute surface, the default is a disaster 8)

Use the cursor keys to highlight the 'CPU (1/1) [Bar]' and hit del to remove it, then slide over to the 'Available meters' column and select 'CPU average', press enter, then use the left right up and down keys to place it where you like in the left or right column meter lists, and press enter again to fix it in that location, then save the lot with 'F10'. Thats really all there is to it.

If setting up is a pain you can save the formats you like to use from ~/.config/htop/htoprc  and replace that file as required

Comment: I guess this is the equivalent indeed of collapsing all the CPUs. It's sad there isn't an easier way, but that works for me. 4096 CPUs is nice :-)